Problemas con el Gradle
hola a tod@s, estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android Studio. Lo que hice fue actualizar el parche de la versión de Android, actualizar el gradle pero nada me parece que funciona. Aquí añado una captura del error:

Cabe mencionar que en ningún archivo ,e aparece errores.

Probablemente el caché de Gradle esté corrupto (tal y  como te lo indica el error que te aparece). Puedes probar haciendo clic en Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network).

Hola Evelyn, bienvenida, los mensajes de error van como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines la imagen y los agregues en el formato correcto, así evitaras que la cierren y recibir votos negativos.
